# MySQL return true/false if col value != specified value

Tags: mysql, database

How can I write a MySQL query that returns true/false (1/0 actually)  based upon the value of a column.

In my instance I want to return  "hasDate" for a date time col, let's call it myDateTime

if myDateTime has a value of 000-00-00 00:00:00  I want to return hasDate of 0 (false)

If myDateTime has any other value I want to return hasDate of 1 (true)

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, but "does not exist" is what NULL is for.

Comment: Worded differently than Joachim, this is a case where `myDateTime` should be nullable. It's less work and more reasonable to query and determine if a column is NULL instead of a specific (bogus) zero-ought value.

Comment: OK, so the best bet would be to change to having a null value instead of the bogus 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value and then to check if Null.  Would the resulting query then be something like:  SELECT col1, col2, col3, IF(myDateTime = NULL,0,1)  WHERE id = 1234 FROM myTable

Comment: NULL is a bit of a special case since it's equal to nothing (including NULL), so you need to check for NULL using `IF(myDateTime IS NULL,0,1)`, otherwise the same as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `IF` statement

```
SELECT IF(myDateTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00',0,1) AS hasDate FROM myTable
```

But the best idea would be to change your data structure to avoid doing that.

Comment: If the table has 10000 rows, this will return 10000 times '0', right?

Comment: Thanks, this should work until I can get the data structure changed.  Unfortunately I don't have the power to do that right now.

Comment: I still don't know how you can test for `0000-00-00 00:00:00` considering MySQL's accepted range is `1000-01-01 00:00:00` through `9999-12-31 23:59:59` (per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html))

Comment: @BradChristie Per the same doc: *The sole exception to this rule is the special “zero” value '0000-00-00'*. `0000-00-00` means `0` for a `DATETIME` field.

Comment: @MathieuImbert: Illegal values are converted to that format. Try inserting the value; you should see `Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 2 to TIMESTAMP` or something similar.

Comment: @BradChristie I tried it, it works: `INSERT INTO pictures (update) VALUES ('0000-00-00 00:00:00')`. It will also default to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` if the field is left uninitialized.