# To check the condition from multiple rows in sql and return true or false

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table X**

```
ColA     ColB      ColC
------------------------
 A       10      Not NULL
 B       20      Not NULL
 C       10      Not NULL
 D       50      Not NULL
 E       20      Not Null
```

I want a statement where `columnB in (10,20)` then return '1' else '0'
Ignore the rest values in ColB

Example output for above table :
1

It should be similar to-

```
Select
case
when ColB is in (10,20) the '1' else '0'
from Table X
where 
ColC is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Seems very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376392/mysql-return-true-false-if-col-value-specified-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, perhaps you're looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when colb in (10,20) then 1 else 0 end) result
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656e5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify better your question?

If I've understand it, all you need is an nested IF statement.

```
SELECT 
    IF(COLB = 10, 1, IF(COLB = 20, 1, 0)) AS MYRES
FROM
    CFGMML_CTARNC01;
```